# How to order data based on a parameter in firestore?

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing an issue while Ordering data based on a parameter. Below is the code snippet.

event_date is a `timestamp`

```
 db.collection("abc")   
 .doc("Events")
  .collection("List")     
  .where("event_status", "==", "0")   
     .orderBy("event_date", "desc").get()      
     .then(function (querySnapshot) {-------------------});
```

The error message thrown is,

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Sun Nov 25 2018 17:27:56 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of Table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, a firebase query retrieves all documents in ascending order of document ID.
You can specify the sort order for your data using `orderBy()`.

In your case `.orderBy("event_date", "desc")` , if you set the field "event_date" using firebase serverTimestamp()
for ex: `.set({event_date = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp() })` you would get the above error.
Inorder to resolve this you may instead set it to `new Date()`
for ex: `.set({event_date =  new Date() })`

In Firebase, `firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` and `new Date()` both would result in a **timestamp**

Hope this helps.